# Questions about truth in deontic logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic, deontology

I'm currently studying a bit of deontic logic due to a course in modal logic that I'm taking and I have some questions.

My main question is regarding truth value in deontic logic. Initially, I understood that deontic logic deals with norms, so letters such as p or q are *generic actions*, such as smoking, walking, paying taxes, etc. When we prefix that action with a deontic modality, such as obligation, we get a norm. If p is "paying taxes", then O(p) is "it is obligatory to pay your taxes". Within this framework, my question is: how do we interpret the truth value of the standalone variables? What does p or q even mean here, considering that they can be "generic actions"?

I also know about SDL (Standard Deontic Logic), where our propositional variables are now actually real propositions, not generic actions. Here, my question is: how does it make sense to prefix a proposition with a modality of obligation, permissibility, etc.? I'm super confused here.

P.S.: My main resource when studying this is [Deontic Logic and Legal Systems](https://www.amazon.com.br/Deontic-Logic-Legal-Systems-Navarro/dp/0521139902) and also [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLz0n_SjOttTeQ8tcWgyV1o8oIyUvtgxX6) on YouTube.

Comment: The action variables, lacking sentential form, would not be true (or false). As for SDL, there would be a carryover from the broader analysis of [propositional attitude reports](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/prop-attitude-reports/).

Comment: I've never seen a discussion of it, but I always assumed p would be something like "one pays ones taxes", not "paying taxes". Then Op would be "it is obligatory that one pays ones taxes".

Comment: Most earlier deontic logics are all SDL like, later you have Dyadic DL (DDL) to rid of some very infamous problematic derivations based on SDL axioms and rules. Your described problem can be referenced as Jorgenson's dilemma. And finally to prefix a proposition with a modality unary operator (binary operator for DDL) is the key creative idea of the whole *intensional* modal logic business which logicians such as Łukasiewicz and Quine vehemently objected...